# java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class ; no empty constructor

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

My app crash,and i get this logCat:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment kostas.menu.rssreader.ListActivity$SampleListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Comment: no, No, NO! You should never ever instantiate an activity by yourself! And you should never ever implement an constructor in your own activity! Don't do that! Stop it, right now!

Comment: @blackbelt this way returns me error

Comment: if you want to pass data to your new activity, use intent extra and not a parameter in a constructor...

Comment: This is not about Activity but Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Your activity does not define a default constructor. Instead of passing titleRes as a constructor parameter, pass it as an intent extra. In your case, you don't need to define a constructor at all, so you can omit it)

```
public onCreate(...) {
  titleRes = getIntent().getIntExtra("titleResId", R.string.default_title);
}
```

To start activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
i.putExtra("titleResId", R.string.my_title);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: an activity should never have a constructor! it only results in errors like above. Just don't say that there should be a constructor!

Comment: I don't agree, sometimes a constructor is perfectly fine and indicated (for instance when making a base abstract activity class). As long as you know what you are doing of course. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MarvinLabs , i have followed your way,but i still get the same first logcat error..

Comment: Give me an example where you need to construct an activity? When do you need an instance of an activity that you will not start via intent? An abstract base activity class can't be instantiated, so why do you need an constructor, then?

Comment: @menu_on_top don't call `new ListActivity()`, where ever you call that, remove it and work with the above sample from MarvinLabs

Comment: @WarrenFaith could you please add some more details?

Comment: what else then "remove the call" should I provide?

Comment: I have completey removes `public ListActivity(int titleRes) { mTitleRes = titleRes; }` and i get a new error.please check my question,i posted it there

Answer (score -1):

ListActivity's super class means SlidingFragmentActivity class is not having constructor with int so you have to call **super()** as first statement from your ListActivity's class constructor.
Please look into the blow code.

```
public ListActivity(int titleRes) {
    super();
    mTitleRes = titleRes;
}
```

Hope this will help you...:)